# Can we add "more" with an adjective to convert it into comparative degree?

Tags: adjectives

We say *"more beautiful"* to refer to someone's beauty as being greater than another person's or other people's beauty. Here we use *more* because *beautiful* has no comparative form. When we deal with the words that have a comparative form, we use the comparative, e.g., "he looks happier today"; here we are using *happier* because *happy* has a comparative form.

But even if an adjective has a comparative form, can we use *more* to compare with others? Do sentences such as "John is more tall than Jack", instead of "John is taller than Jack" sound odd?

Comment: If the adjective forms its comparative with *-er*, a comparative with *more* is always incorrect. Your terminology, by the way, is non-standard (though perfectly comprehensible): *more beautiful* ***is*** the comparative of *beautiful*

Answer (score 2):

Please see the previous question and answer here, which is closely related to yours: ["bigger" vs. "more big"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/bigger-vs-more-big/1285#1285)

1. Does the adjective *beautiful,* and others like it, have a comparative form?  Yes, they do. That particular premise of your post (that *beautiful* does **not** have a comparative form) is incorrect.  *Beautiful* is a longer adjective (see the previous, linked post for the details) and the comparative form is *more + adjective.*
2. Can *more* be used together with a comparative to somehow **further** or **more intensely** compare two things?  In a word, **no.**  *More better* is incorrect; *more taller* is incorrect, and *more more beautiful* is also incorrect.  If you want to intensify these comparisons, use **much + comparative adjective**: *much better, much taller, much more beautiful.*

Comment: The OP is assuming adjectives do have a comparative degree; that is not something he is questioning.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, OP specifically wrote that ""beautiful" has no comparative form"

Comment: Maybe he means that _beautifuller_ is not a word. Then, the OP is not talking of _more taller_, but _more tall_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I want to make peace with you, but maybe this particular post is not the place to do so.  I fail to see how your suppositions about what OP might have intended negate my response.  However, you and I have butted heads before when it was after midnight my time and afterwards I had to eat my hat, so please clarify.  As far as my foggy mind can comprehend, the previous, linked post, together with my answer to this post, sufficiently answers OP's queries; on the other hand, your follow-ups seem but red herrings.  I have eaten my hat on stack-exchange before, so...give me more.

Comment: I have never eaten anybody's hat, nor have I eaten [@nohat](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/39/nohat)'s hat. You open your answer saying that this question is not a duplicate, but what you are supposing asked from the OP is not what the OP is asking. It seems the OP is (wrongly) using _comparative_ for words like _taller_, and not _more beautiful_; when he says _beautiful_ doesn't have the comparative, he means _beautifuller_ is not an English word. Then, he is not asking about _more taller_, but _more tall_, for which there is already a question, even if that is about _bigger_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, sadly, you have not responded in kind ("where is the love?"), and I don't want to sound snarky, BUT, we seem to be interpreting OP's post differently; I was certainly giving him the benefit of the doubt, but because of the unintelligible grammar in your latest response, I cannot quite follow the objections you are raising about my answer when considered alongside the previous post and its answers, including mine, as I urged it must be. Please show me how my current answer to OP, when considered alongside the earlier post, is lacking... The hat-eating offer still stands..

Comment: @ShawnMooney At the risk of sticking my nose into someone else's conversation, I agree with kiamlaluno. OP is *not* asking about phrases like "more taller". He *explicitly* uses the examples "John is *more tall* than Jack" and "John is *taller* than Jack" (emphasis mine) to demonstrate his meaning. Thus, your comments regarding the unrelated *more taller* are off topic; OP simply wants to know whether *more tall* is correct *even though* there exists a one-word comparator, "taller", and if so, which is preferred.

Comment: @KenB, stick your nose anywhere you like. OP's post has been edited numerous times (including by me), and has now been marked as 'duplicate', so I am not sure which version you've responded to. Taking such 'moving goal posts' into account, I hope both you and kiamlaluno can agree that _taller_ is correct as a comparative for the short adjective "tall", that "more taller" is ungrammatical, and that my response to OP's post today, considered together with the earlier, linked post, dispenses with your objections...). If not, repost!  It is 1:55 am Tokyo time and time for bed!

Comment: @ShawnMooney There is *no* version of this post in which the OP asked about "more taller".

Comment: I am afraid I might have to say that @KenB and kiamlaluno has got my question rightly. Maybe due to my poor word choice Shwan is misled. I am apologizing to Shawn for that.

Comment: @KenB, it is indeed true that OP did not ask about "more taller", and I thank you for bringing this to my/our attention.  I failed to transcribe nor did I correct OP's grammatical error, but surely it is contextually obvious in OP that he was asking whether there is, in fact, any difference between (1) _Jack is taller than Jill_ and _Jack is more tall than Jill_, grammatically or otherwise,; again, based on my previous response in conjunction with the linked-answer (which umpteen fuss-budgets seem to want to shut down this dialogue in favor of) can you not agree that I have a valid point?

Comment: @Mistu4u, no need to apologize. I intend to review all of these comments with fresh eyes in the morning, and add to the dialogue or correct my part it in accordingly.  I have already violated my no-posting/commenting-after midnight rule.  :)